# Compare SAS Data Step and PROC SQL using Concatenate function

Tags: performance, sas, concatenation, proc-sql, datastep

Following is the Data Step I am trying to work on. I am a beginner in SAS. I want to compare the performance of SAS DATA Step and PROC SQL using concatenation. I tried to do it but i am not getting the same output for the DATA step and proc SQL. Hence, i cant compare the performance- which one is better?
eg-> I tried concatenating Ridings (dataset) and REsults (dataset). But output was different.
Can somebody help me with this? [Link for reference](https://kaggle.com/smid80/canadian-federal-election-results-timeseries)

Comment: Please show your code, as text (not links or photographs). In what way are the results different between the two attempts?

Comment: Hi, please review the guidelines on how to post a question here [ask]. Ideally, show us your code at minimum and what makes you think it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

SQL data stacking (or what you might call concatenation) is accomplished with a `UNION` statement.  However, UNION will remove duplicates.  Try `UNION ALL` to maintain any duplicates that occur in the stacked data.

In SAS the highest performing operation for data stacking might be `PROC APPEND`.